# Get data in console but not shown in the page Angular 7

Tags: angular

When I gete data via http request I get data and view it in console but not shown in page

I send to request data from ngfor to view it as per the section

In component page

```
items: Teams[]=[];      
dataKeys(team:string,sub:number) {
  this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.service.getteam(this.id,team,sub).subscribe((data) => {
    this.items = data;
    console.log(this.items);
    return this.items;
  });        
}
```

In html page

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let result of dataKeys(team,sub)">
    {{ result.firstName }} {{result.middleName}} {{result.familyName}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

the data shown in console but not shown in html page

Answer (score 3):

dataKeys is a function which does not return anything..... call dataKeys in your ngOnInit and then use

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let result of items">
   {{ result.firstName }} {{result.middleName}} {{result.familyName}}
</mat-list-item>
```

Comment: I need to be a function to get data depending on prameters because its not one list its 12 and every list has its data

Comment: is this an http call?

Comment: yes as it is shown in the first code it's call to http service

Comment: calling a function which makes an http call from your view is very dangerous because it will make the http call every time change detection runs. Where does the data come from for team and sub?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to return an observable in the service (as good practice).

```
return this.service.getteam(this.id,team,sub);
```

In your component creates an observable:

```
public items$: Observable<Team[]>;
```

Then create a function that assigns the value returned by your service to the observable items$.

```
dataKeys(team:string,sub:number) {
        this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.items$ = this.service.getteam(this.id,team,sub);
}
```

Finally use the pipe async in the html:

```
 <mat-list role="list">
 <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let result of (items$ | async)">
     {{ result.firstName }} {{result.middleName}} {{result.familyName}}
  </mat-list-item>
```

The pipe async is very powerful. It gives your code more cleanliness and simplicity. If you want to delve into the subject, read [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794)

Comment: and how it'll send the prameter and get the data from dataKeys function

Comment: Call the function dataKeys() in the method ngOnInit().

Comment: How do you get the values of the team and sub variables? In the component.ts? If so, you should not have problems. Calling a function in the html is not good.

Comment: the data of teams and sub sent as an array not http call

Comment: You store that values (teams and sub) in the component.ts. So that, you can call the function dataKeys(teams, sub) in the method onInit()